# 'get_all_connections' no attribute error with Facebook GraphAPI

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to create a script to fetch all data from Facebook using GraphAPI but i have been having trouble using the 'get_all_connections' method but in the documentation http://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html, they dont seem to mention any problems. Here's the script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS 
import requests
import facebook

token = 'mytoken'

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token = token, version='2.7')
friends = graph.get_all_connections(id='id', 
connection_name='comments')

print friends
```

Output is

```
AttributeError: 'GraphAPI' object has no attribute 'get_all_connections'
```

Answer (score 3):

The Facebook **[Changelog](https://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changes.html#version-3-0-0-unreleased)** says that `get_all_connections()` will be available in **Version 3.0.0 (unreleased)**.

(There's a link to the **Changelog** on the side_menu in the link you provided, right below **API Reference**.)

Calling it **"Latest"** is pretty misleading... and just plain lazy ;o)